# Same Array Different Results

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, gist

The function `closest` in the script tags, finds a number closest to `112`. However when I use this same function on an identical array from an ajax request, it gives the wrong result.

**Console log 1**: The local `array` produces the correct result `122`.

**Console log 2**: External `array2` shown to be identical to the local one.

**Console log 3**: Using the external array results in a left bracket. Removing the brackets from the `gist` results in `8`, which is still incorrect.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nepqsco/)

```js
function loadgist(gistid, filename)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/' + gistid,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    }).success(function(gistdata) {
        var content = gistdata.data.files[filename].content;
        DoSomethingWith(content)
    }).error(function(e) {
        // ajax error
    });        
}

function DoSomethingWith(content)
{
    number = 112;
    var array2 = (content);
    console.log(content);
    console.log(closest(number, array2));
}

loadgist("9544dfd755418e819810312488e7986c", "gistfile1.txt");
```

```html
<script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js></script>
<script language="javascript">

function closest(num, arr)
{
    var curr = arr[0];
    var diff = Math.abs (num - curr);

    for (var val = 0; val < arr.length; val++)
    {
        var newdiff = Math.abs (num - arr[val]);

        if (newdiff < diff)
        {
            diff = newdiff;
            curr = arr[val];
        }
    }

    return curr;
}

array = [2, 42, 82, 122, 162, 202, 242, 282, 322, 362];
number = 112;
console.log(closest (number, array));

</script>
```

Comment: `function closest (num, arr) { console.log(typeof arr)`

Comment: Dropdown menu built with array from Ajax request. [http://jsfiddle.net/5vb6hgs9/](http://jsfiddle.net/5vb6hgs9/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `console.log(typeof content)` inside the method `DoSomethingWith(...)` you will note that the content is not an `array`, instead it is a `string`. So use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get an `array` from the `string`, like this:

```
function DoSomethingWith(content)
{
    let number = 112;
    let array2 = JSON.parse(content);
    console.log(content);
    console.log(closest(number, array2));
}
```

Comment: If you have time, what other expressions would you recommend, that are as useful as 'type of' for debugging purposes. Just an observation but in the browser's developer tools the first console log evaluates the entry with color and the other entries are black. Do strings evaluate as black? Much appreciated and many thanks Shidersz.

Comment: @DerekM Sorry, but for debugging, no other one comes to my mind right now. As about the style used to shown the data on the developer console I think it could depend on the browser. Personally, I won't assume nothing universal from that.